# default messages in jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've setup a form validator width jquery, it contains error- and success-messages.

Is it possible to define default messages like "Choose a password" which are shown when the form is loaded and the user doesn't have fill out a field?

Example for password:

- In Case of an error: "Passwords doesn't match"
- In Case of success: "OK!";
- else "Please choose a password"

Addendum: Error messages are shown as label beside the fields

```
        $("#Formular").validate({
        success: function(label) {
        label.addClass('valid').html("ok!") },

        rules: {
            nick: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 20
                },

            nick: {
                required: "choose a name!" }
```

and the html code

```
<input type="text" name="nick"></input> 
<label class="error valid" for="nick" generated="true"></label>
```

Comment: Yes, HTML5 "placeholder" attribute. For dynamic placeholders, [this article](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html) might help. And I'm sure there must be many other good articles on the subject.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: Nice, didnt know this attribute. BUT: my fault... my messages are shown as label beside the fields

Comment: You can write client-side validation code yourself, or use one of several [jQuery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/?s=validate), which are available to "simplify" development.

Comment: Your question is greatly lacking in code and detail.  Are you already using a plugin?

Comment: @Sparky: I've added the code and only use the jquery validation plugin